# Extract result from Algorithmia response

Tags: swift, algorithmia

I have deployed a machine learning model on algorithmia. The model returns a array. Here is my code:

```
    let input = "[82811,4,67,1,1,4]"
    let client = Algorithmia.client(simpleKey: "xxxxx")
    let algo = client.algo(algoUri: "xxxxx/xxxxx/0.1.4")
    algo.pipe(rawJson: input) { resp, error in
        if (error == nil){
            print(resp)

        }
        else {print(error!)}
    }
```

I suppose to get an array like **[12.3456]** by print(resp). However, the output from the console is 
**algorithmia.AlgoResponse** which is not my expected output. I have tried resp.getData(), resp.getText() but it didn't work.

The model work properly on my jupyter notebook and it can successfully output the result which is an array using python:

```
import Algorithmia

input = [82811,4,67,0,0,8]
client = Algorithmia.client('mykey')
algo = client.algo('xxxxx/xxxxx/0.1.4')
algo.set_options(timeout=300)
print(algo.pipe(input).result)
```

So my question is, how to extract the array from AlgoResponse using swift? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you should reformat your input like "[\"82811\",\"4\",\"67\",\"1\",\"1\",\"4"\]". I'm not sure that this is your problem but it is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is not the problem. There is no any error from my code. I just don't know how to extract the result from AlgoResponse.

Comment: According to their git page here https://github.com/algorithmiaio/algorithmia-swift/blob/master/Algorithmia/Client/AlgoResponse.swift , you can try resp.getJson() or a simple resp.get() . Perhaps that will help, if that still doesn't help, you could set a breakpoint in your code and see how resp looks in the debugger.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks.